# Regex search and replace on Apache header edit

Tags: regex, apache, pcre

I have the next code on a .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Content-Security-Policy "base-uri http://site.local/"
        Header append Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'"
        Header append Content-Security-Policy "connect-src 'self'"
        Header append Content-Security-Policy "style-src 'self'"
        Header edit Content-Security-Policy "," ";"
</IfModule>
```

which generates the next response header from the server:

```
Content-Security-Policy base-uri http://site.local/, default-src 'none', connect-src 'self', style-src 'self'
```

I want to get that line with semicolons instead of commas, like this:

```
Content-Security-Policy base-uri http://site.local/; default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self'; style-src 'self'
```

[Using append or merge on Apache's mod_headers separates the different additions to the header previously set with a comma](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header), as the standard seems to point, but the [W3C dictates that the different configurations of the Content Security Policy have to be separated with a semicolon](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#policy-syntax).

I can't find a way to write the Header edit line to replace the ',' with ';' as per the W3C states.

I have tried many variations for the search, I know that some are wrong but since I'm not getting the expected results I'm trying anything that I can think of.

I have tried patterns like this:

- "," with and without quotes, both replace the first occurrence only.
- /,/ with and without quotes, nothing happens.
- /,/g with and without quotes, nothing happens.
- ...

What am I missing?

Comment: How about `Header edit* Content-Security-Policy , ;`? (Notice `*`)

Comment: That just did it, thank you very much.Would you be so kind as to write the comment as an answer with a bit of explanation?. I want to give you the upvote but also would like to understand the process because that * just baffled me

Comment: I think I see it. In the documentation for the 2.4 version of Apache there is an edit and an edit*. I interpreted that * as something extra, something to consider or differentiate from the original edit, like edit and edit2, not as an actual option since no other option has non alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Header directive accepts two different arguments in order to perform a substitution. The one that performs a global match has a trailing asterisk `edit*`. From [documents](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#page-header):

> The `edit` form will match and replace exactly once in a header value, whereas the `edit*` form will replace every instance of the search pattern if it appears more than once.

You need `edit*` as in:

```
Header edit* Content-Security-Policy , ;
```